# Javascript Object: find a key/value when in range

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, key, range

i have a Javascript object like this one:

```
pItems = {
 single : {
  ...
  plz: {
   "1000": 12,
   "2000-2500" : 40
   "3000": 30  
  }
  ...
 }
}
```

i get a value from an inputfield e.g. "2300" and now i need the value for this "2300" from the object. Because 2300 is in the range of the plz-key "2000-2500" the value i should get back is "40".

i have no clue atm how i could find the right value, if i am looking up something in key "ranges".

thank you for any advice, help with that.

Comment: What would you return if they would input, I dunno, 1500?

Answer (score 4):

You can iterate over the keys, split them, if possible and perform a check. If in range, then return the item and leave the loop.

```js
function getItem(value) {
    var item;
    Object.keys(object.plz).some(function (k) {
        var part = k.split('-');
        if (+value >= part[0] && +value <= (part[1] || part[0])) {
            item = object.plz[k];
            return true;
        }
    });
    return item;
}

var object = { plz: { "1000": 12, "2000-2500": 40, "3000": 30 } };

console.log(getItem('1000'));
console.log(getItem('2300'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Wraped as function:

```
function getValue(search) {
    for( var range in pItems.plz ) {
        var split = range.split("-");

        if( search >= parseInt(split[0]) && search <= parseInt(split[1] || split[0]) )
            return pItems.plz[range];
    }
}
```

Call:

```
console.log(getValue(1000)); // 12
console.log(getValue(2300)); // 40
console.log(getValue(3000)); // 30
console.log(getValue(5000)); // undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var pItems = {
 single : {
  plz: {
   "1000": 12,
   "2000-2500" : 40,
   "3000": 30  
  }
 }
};

var val =2300 ;
 $.each(pItems.single.plz, function(k,v) {
   var min = parseInt(k.split('-')[0]);
   var max = parseInt(k.split('-')[1]);
   if(isNaN(max) ){
      if(min == val){
         console.log(v);
         return;
      }
   }else if(val>=min || val <= max){
       console.log(v);
       return;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: wow that was quick, and full code!! thx a lot! wasn't expect a full solution :).